# Creating a form that posts to Twitter - how to get started?

Tags: authentication, twitter

I'm trying to figure out how to create an HTML form that would allow a user to log in and tweet their message directly to Twitter. What resources should I look at to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form target="_blank" name="tweet" action="https://twitter.com/share" method="get"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="original_referer" value="http://www.yoururl.com"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="source" value="tweetbutton"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.yoururl.com"> 
  <input style="width:430px; height:34px; font-size:18px" type="text" name="text" maxlength="98">

  <input type="submit" value="Tweet This" />    
</form>
```